# Списки .ul .li text-align:justify один блог(через каждый 6-ой) выпрыгивает вверх

Tags: html, css, ul

http://archiess.github.io/ - помогите разобраться, не знаю как решить проблему со списками, один блок выпрыгивает, и как отменить justify внутри li, что бы выровнять текст по центру.

https://github.com/Archiess/archiess.github.io - код

html

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center">
        <h1>Pokedex</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        <ul id="pokemon-list"></ul>
        <div id="pokemon-list-loader"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
        <button id="load-more" class="btn btn-success">Load more</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div id="pokemon"></div>
        <div id="pokemon-loader"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
function loadMorePokemons()
{
    $('#pokemon-list-loader').show();

    $.get(getLoadMoreUrl(), function (data) {
      page++;

      var template = '';

      $.each(data.objects, function (i, pokemon) {
        template += `
          <li class="pokemon" id="${pokemon.national_id}">
            <img class="image" src="${getPokemonImageUrl(pokemon.national_id)}" /><br>
            <b>${pokemon.name}</b>
            <div>${getTypes(pokemon.types)}</div>
          </li>
        `;
      });

      $('#pokemon-list').append(template);
      $('#pokemon-list-loader').hide();
    });
}
```

css

```
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:justify;
  line-height:0;
  /*margin:0;*/
  padding:0;*/
  /*для IE-6-7*/
  text-justify:newspaper;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

ul:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:normal;
  height:250px;
  width:150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style:none;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Куда смотреть, что выпрыгивает? И как понять это `отменить justify внутри li, что бы выровнять текст по центру`?

Comment: Добавь минимальный пример прямо в вопрос.

Comment: я указываю изначально для всех блоков ul{text-align:justify}, потом хочу что бы внутри блоков <li> было ul li {text-align: center} , но это не работает.

Comment: Если перейти по первой ссылке и посмотреть на 7ой блок то он выбивается вверх почему то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте у элемента `ul li` изменить параметр `display` на `inline-table`. Файл app.css cтрока 80.

```
ul li{
display: inline-table;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, но как теперь в блоке li текст по центру сделать?